# payload is undefined i have an empty array when i add product to my shopping cart

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am getting an error from reducer product not found. please help me resolve this issue. I have consoled data and payload in action it is working fine. but in cartscreen addtocart action is failing to get action and state, in redux dev tools a have an empty array in state cart [], also i  have this error when i run my app:  Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client [0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)

this is my code

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {CART_ADD_ITEM} from '../constants/CartConstants'

export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)
  try {

  dispatch({
    type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
      product: data._id,
      name: data.name,
      front: data.front,
      back:data.back,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.countInStock,
      qty,
    },
  })
}catch(e){
  console.error(e);
}

  localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
  localStorage.getItem('cartItems');

}
import {CART_ADD_ITEM} from '../constants/CartConstants'

export  const cartReducers =(state = { cartItems: [] }, action) =>{
  switch(action.type){
    case CART_ADD_ITEM:
      const item=action.payload
      const existItem=state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product===item.product)
      if(existItem){
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems:state.cartItems.map((x) => x.product === existItem.product ? item : x),
        }
      }
  else {
    return{
      ...state,
      cartItems :[...state.cartItems, item]
    }
  }
  default:
    return state
}
}
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import {productListReducer, productDetailsReducer} from './reducers/productReducers'
import {cartReducers} from './reducers/cartReducers'

const reducer=combineReducers({
    productList:productListReducer,
  productDetails:productDetailsReducer,
  cart:cartReducers,
})
const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')): []
const intialState={
  cart: {cartItems:cartItemsFromStorage}
}
const middleware=[thunk]

const  store=createStore(reducer, intialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store;

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Container, ListGroupItem } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Link from 'react-router-dom'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {Row, Col, ListGroup, Image,Form, Button, Card} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {addToCart} from '../actions/cartActions'
import Message from '../Message'

export default function Cart({match, location,history}) {
    const productId = match.params.id

    const qty = location.search ? Number(location.search.split('=')[1]) : 1
  
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    useEffect(() => {
        if (productId) {
          dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty))
        }
      }, [dispatch, productId, qty])
console.log(qty)      
const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart)
const { cartItems } = cart
console.log(cartItems)
    return (
        <Container>
            cart
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: The latter error (setting response header) probably comes from the server. Since you posted only the client code, let's consider that unrelated.

Comment: "product not found" sounds like an error from the server as well... since your client calls `/api/products/<some id>` the question is, what that `id` is. One possibility is that when `Cart` is rendered, the URI `match` doesn't have a product id set. I'm assuming there's something like `ReactRouter` in play.

Comment: Overall, it seems that the code is made to work like this: when user navigates to e.g. `products/88?whatever=42`, then code attempts to add (or update) `42` items of product `88`. The design is questionable. Usually, cart should be update in response to user action (clicking a button, etc.) rather than merely navigation.